# AVD blackscreen after enableLocalDatastore

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-virtual-device

Has anyone experienced something like this ? My app works but after I add the line "Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);" in my Application class it stops. Eclipse tries to launch it but right after the white screen, it turns black and LogCat notifies this warning "*05-24 14:15:20.683: W/ActivityManager(382): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!*"

First time I experience such thing, tried searching on Parse.com and nothing.

Additional info:

- Android + Google APIs v4.4.2
- Parse v1.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it wasn't the SDK's fault.

Solution: Had to create a new AVD to test my app after adding the line "enableLocalDatastore".

Answer (score 0):

^true, same here, I lost ~10h to find out why!!!! seems it is **parse.com** lib BUG!!!!! when build the android application on release mode!!!!!!!

solution add this :

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
```

before

```
Parse.initialize
```