# Blackscreen after enableLocalDatastore

Tags: android, parse-platform

I think i experience the same problem described in this post [AVD blackscreen after enableLocalDatastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848300/avd-blackscreen-after-enablelocaldatastore)
but creating a new ADV did answer the problem.

My app already use a Sqlite database maybe this base creates conflict with the Parse library.
I tried to launch the Todolist example given by Parse on the same Emulator and it works.

I debug my app and i see that this is the Parse.initialize function that freeze which is one of the first lines of my application.

```
    // add Todo subclass
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Shoes.class);

    // enable the Local Datastore
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
    Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID", "Client_ID");
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

I can't see how to debug this thing to known what existing element in my app is freezing Parse library...

Additional info:

- Parse v1.6.0
- Android + Google APIs v4.4.2

Comment: I have the same problem. Recreating the AVD does not seem to fix it. GenyMotion also fails in the same way. I don't use a Sqlite database (yet) so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Exactly in the same page. The application get stuck in simulator at Parse.initialize() call when `enableDataStore` is added. It simply works fine if I remove the `enableDataStore` call and remove the pin lines. Surprised that very few people faced this problem!